# Launching given activities directly

Tags: android, breadth-first-search

I'd like to create run configurations within Eclipse to launch a given Android activity directly so I don't have to run through my entire application to get to it. In my manifest, I've declared the activity like so:

```
<activity
    android:name=".AlternativeActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_alternative_activity"
    android:exported="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.mysite.AlternativeActivity" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />               
    </intent-filter>
</activity
```

However, in Eclipse, I'm seeing the following warning:

```
Exported activity does not require permission.
```

How do I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Exported activities (activities which either set exported=true or
>   contain an intent-filter and do not specify exported=false) should
>   define a permission that an entity must have in order to launch the
>   activity or bind to it. Without this, any application can use this
>   activity.

Protip: Place your cursor on the warning, press CTRL + 1 and select "Explain Issue".